# Migrating from sharepoint 2003 to 2010

Tags: 2010, migration, 2003

Is there a more direct path to migrate SharePoint from 2003 to 2010 without having to go through 2007? Has there been any recent development that allows admins to do that?

EDIT Update has been changed to migrate, since upgrade is not possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Quest Migration Manager](http://www.quest.com/Migration-Manager-for-SharePoint/) allows you to go from 2003 to 2010 as does [Metavis Migrator](http://metavistech.com/product/sharepoint-migration) and [Metalogix Migration Manager](http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Migration-Manager-for-SharePoint/SharePoint-Upgrade.aspx).

Comment: AvePoint's Migrator product also supports a migration from 2003 to 2010.

Comment: Hey PitareEric, if you are familiar with Quest Software i would like to ask how does this software react on documents that are checked-out or unpublished? I mean under the migrations process.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no experience using any of the migration products, I just know they exist and will allow you to jump versions.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended path is always through 2007. There have been no attempts made to bridge this and Microsoft say it is not possible here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ee947140.aspx

Comment: Are you sure?  I thought Quest and Metavis and possibly Metalogix had tools that would allow you to go from 2003 to 2010 without having to install a 2007 farm.

Comment: Migrate, but not a direct upgrade. Maybe I'm talking semantics now ;)

Comment: Classic SharePoint, "it depends" ;-D

Comment: Very true Eric :)

Comment: So the question should be migrate, which is understandbly not an upgrade. Got it

Answer (score 0):

When you are thinking to migrate from SP2003 to SP2010, most probably you want to migrate only the content (and users in some cases). Here are some tools which can do that : http://cmsreport.com/comment/11878

Due to heavy architecture difference from 2003 to 2010, of course you cannot migrate anything based on features in SP2003 that are discontinued in SP2010. Here are some obsolete features of 2003 which for which you have to re-develop : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179142(office.12).aspx